# Los botones se salen del div al disminuir el navegador

Tags: css

Cuando disminuyo el navegador los botones del css se me salen , y lo que quiero es que se ajusten al tamaño del div , y no consigo hacerlo. Además se me desplaza hacia la derecha cuando también disminuyo el tamaño del navegador , hay también alguna forma de dejar fijos los botones en su sitio?

```
.form__btns{
  margin-left:130px;
  display: flex;
}
```

Inicialmente están así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al disminuir el navegador así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas usando tamaños absolutos
Esto significa que siempre habrán 130px como margen izquierdo, sin importar el tamaño.
Lo que deberías usar es `vw`- Viewport Width. 
Esto es una medida de unidad relativa al 1% del ancho del viewport.
Prueba diferentes medidas hasta dar con el tamaño ideal.

```
.form__btns{
  margin-left:5vw;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Ósea que con la medida viewport  se adapta a la anchura y altura cuando toque el tamaño del navegador si no te he entendido mal

Comment: Exacto, y lo que menciona BetaM anteriormente también es cierto.

Comment: No sé qué ha mencionado BetaM , lo ha borrado?

Comment: Al parecer si, no se por que, es decisión de el. Te ha dado resultado ?